# Can't find assimp header files

Tags: c++, cmake, assimp

I'm using CMake and I have a number of external libraries I'm using.

Under a folder

```
`ext/
 - eigen
 - glm
 - glfw
`
```

All of this compiles fine and I can run my code properly. However, I installed assimp by cloning a repo into `ext/` and I updated my CMakeLists.txt to be

```
### Add src to the include directories
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")

### Include Eigen for linear algebra
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/eigen")

### Include glm for other math
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/glm")

include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/assimp") # new line
```

And when I go to my main and write

```
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
```

VSCode doesn't complain. However, when I compile it I get

"fatal error: 'assimp/Importer.hpp' file not found"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As you are cloning the entire repository you need to add `include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/assimp/include")` to your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @vre Doing that fixed the immediate problem but now I'm getting `ext/assimp/include/assimp/defs.h:53:10: fatal error: 'assimp/config.h' file not found` which is not even my file.

Comment: Have you tried `include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext` **only** ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the assimp header files you'll need to include `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/assimp/include"` since that's where they're located in the repository. Since assimp is not a header-only library - unlike the others you have listed - you'll need to link against it as well. Your compiler is complaining about config.h because it doesn't actually exist (it should be in `assimp/include/`. If you check there you'll see there is a config.h.in which is used to generate the mission config.h file during the build step so that's why you don't have it.

If you want to add the assimp sources to your project you can use `add_subdirectory(ext/assimp)`. Due to it's size you might want to install assimp as a system dependency and then use the `find_package()` directive to bring it in to your project.